# If an enchanted creature is untargetable, is the enchantment on the creature directly targetable?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I had recently played a game with someone I hadn't played before, and they threw down a dark depths/thespian's stage combo. I in turn enchanted it to be an indestructible 0/1 that couldn't be the target of spells or abilities. He said that the enchantment though can be still targeted by "Destroy target enchantment" abilities which didn't make sense with how I have understood the game. Who's right in this situation? Can the enchantment be targeted or is it untargetable because it's on an untargetable creature?

Comment: *Exactly* what effect did you use on the Marit Lage token?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The enchantment can be targeted. The enchantment is a completely separate object from the creature that it’s enchanting. Enchantments can have shroud; and then they would be untargetable. See [Greater Auramancy](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Greater%20Auramancy).